# How to sign out of Microsoft and Github with Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, github-oauth, microsoft-oauth

I can't seem to force a sign out of Github or Microsoft they way I do for Google. With the help of the google_sign_in package.

```
  Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> _signOutWithGoogle() async {
    return Chain.capture(() async {
      try {
        return await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
      } on Exception catch (error, stackTrace) {
        final terseStacktrace = Chain.forTrace(stackTrace).terse;

        logger.e(
          "GoogleSignOutException",
          error: error,
          stackTrace: terseStacktrace,
        );

        rethrow;
      }
    });
  }

    Future<Result<void, LogOutFailure>> signOut() async {
    try {
      if (_auth.currentUser?.providerData.first.providerId == "google.com") {
        await _signOutWithGoogle();
      }

      await _auth.signOut();

      return const Result.success(null);
    } catch (_) {
      return const Result.error(LogOutFailure());
    }
  }
```

Without a signout from the package, I'll be automatically logged in as the previous credential I used and I won't be able to change it.

The same issue persists for Microsoft and Github sign ins.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

    Future<UserCredential> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
      final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
      if (kIsWeb) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
      } else {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
      }
    }
```

Calling `_auth.signOut()` isn't enough since it only signs out the firebase user not the github or microsoft user.

Is there a package or implementation I can use to solve this?

Comment: I will post an answer and see if it can help you since i'm not able to post long message here in comment, else if not useful, inform me so i will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

1. For Microsoft, you can use the `logoutRedirect` method from the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL). This method clears the local cache of user tokens and redirects the window to the server signout page. This is a more comprehensive signout solution.

```
Future<UserCredential> signOutWithMicrosoft() async {
 final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
 if (kIsWeb) {
   await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
 } else {
   await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
 }
 // Use MSAL's logoutRedirect method here
}
```

2. For GitHub, there isn't a direct method to sign out the user. One workaround is to navigate to https://github.com/logout to log out from GitHub. However, this is not a programmatic solution. You may want to consider using a webview to navigate to this URL and then close the webview.

```
Future<void> _signOutWithGithub() async {
 final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
 await Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://github.com/logout',
       javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
       onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
         _controller.complete(webViewController);
       },
       navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
         if (request.url.startsWith('https://github.com/login')) {
           Navigator.pop(context);
           return NavigationDecision.prevent;
         }
         return NavigationDecision.navigate;
       },
     );
   }),
 );
}
```

Then, remember to call these methods in your `signOut` method:

```
Future<Result<void, LogOutFailure>> signOut() async {
 try {
   if (_auth.currentUser?.providerData.first.providerId == "microsoft.com") {
     await signOutWithMicrosoft();
   } else if (_auth.currentUser?.providerData.first.providerId == "GitHub.com") {
    await _signOutWithGithub();
```

Comment: Any signOutGitHub snippet you want to show me? I've updated my post to include the _signOutWithGoogle I created. There's no signOutMicrosoft or signOutGitHub code out there.

Comment: I edit the answer. It seems I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I see. Looks like the user needs to sign in on github on the device otherwise they're redirected to github.com but I'm sure I can put a prompt somewhere. Thanks a lot.